# DOM to access the parent of Previous element if the child element has active class

Tags: javascript

i am trying to access parent of Previous element `<li><span class="toggle-arrow-down menus">Test</span>` whenever the child element has active class from below HTML structure using javascript.

```
<li><span class="toggle-arrow-down menus">Test</span>
<ul class="nested">
   <li>>Test1</a></li>
   <li>
     <li><span class="toggle-arrow menus toggle-arrow-down">Test2</span>
        <ul class="nested">
            <li><a aria-current="page" class="active">Test3</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I have tried with below code

```
var selected = document.querySelector('ul li a.active');]
var closestMenu = selected && selected.closest('.nested');
var span = closestMenu && closestMenu.closest('.toggle-arrow-down');
```

Please help me in accessing the parent of Previous element in javascript

Comment: The `span` is not the *parent* of the `ul` element, it's its sibling. I'm surprised you're getting anything logged at all.

Comment: Do you want like this? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/rNxMeOW